# Send data from PHP to Java tcp listener

Tags: java, php

So, I have a very basic test set up to see if i can send data from a php web page to a java app running on the same server.

The java app is dead simple, it just listens on a TCP socket for data

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer
{
   public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
      {
         String clientSentence;
         String capitalizedSentence;
         ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

         while(true)
         {
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient =
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
            connectionSocket.close(); //this line was part of the solution
         }
      }
}
```

I have tried two ways to send and read the response with php, but none seem to work. I get a connection OK and data sent OK, but the server doesn't print anything nor respond with anything so I dont know why it's saying it's OK :)

**Method 1**

```
$host = "tcp://localhost"; 
$port = 6789;
$data = 'test' . PHP_EOL;  //Adding PHP_EOL was the other part of the solution
$errstr = '';
$errno = '';

if ( ($fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 3) ) === FALSE)
    echo "$errstr ($errno)";
else {
    print 'SUCCESS!<br />';
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    while (! feof($fp)) {
      echo fgets($fp, 4096);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Method 2**

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$port = 6789;
$data = 'test';

if ( ($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === FALSE )
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
else 
{
    echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'...<br>";
    if ( ($result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port)) === FALSE )
        echo "socket_connect() failed. Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    else {
        echo "Sending data...<br>";
        socket_write($socket, $data, strlen($data));
        echo "OK<br>";

        echo "Reading response:<br>";
        while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
            echo $out;
        }
    }
    socket_close($socket);      
}
```

**EDIT**

Apparently fsockopen() has a problem connecting to localhost from a comment I found at [PHP fsockopen doesnt return anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876478/php-fsockopen-doesnt-return-anything) so changed to 127.0.0.1 but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try changing `$data = 'test'` to `$data = "test\n"` and see if that helps.
- Close the socket on the server when your done otherwise the client will block in the `while` loop waiting for more data:

  ```
   outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
   connectionSocket.close()
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately not but thanks. Also tried "test" . PHP_EOL just in case :)

Comment: Code is as you see it. Thats the whole php page and the whole java page.

Comment: I'm not sure where the flush() would logicaly go? Just after the write maybe?... Anyway, tried it on several lines and still no go.  Coincedentially, doesnt work run from the shell line direct on the server either.

Comment: That command doesnt work, I get usage instructions back `# nc -l -p 6789
usage: nc [-46DdhklnrStUuvzC] [-i interval] [-p source_port]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-T ToS] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]`

Comment: added `connectionSocket.close()`, still nothing...  still hangs at `fgets`.

Comment: GOT IT!!! It was a combination of two things you said. 1) Adding the \n to the end of the data (I actually added PHP_EOL) and adding the `connectionSocket.close()`